# Trying to follow django docs to create serialized json

Tags: python, json, django-fixtures

Trying to seed a database in django app. I have a csv file that I converted to json and now I need to reformat it to match the django serialization required format found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json)
This is what the json format needs to look like to be acceptable to django (Which looks an awful lot like a dictionary with 3 keys, the third having a value which is a dictionary itself):

```
[
    {
        "pk": "4b678b301dfd8a4e0dad910de3ae245b",
        "model": "sessions.session",
        "fields": {
            "expire_date": "2013-01-16T08:16:59.844Z",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

My json data looks like this after converting it from csv with pandas:

```
[{'model': 'homepage.territorymanager', 'pk': 1, 'Name': 'Aaron ##', 'Distributor': 'National Energy', 'State': 'BC', 'Brand': 'Trane', 'Cell': '778-###-####', 'email address': None, 'Notes': None, 'Unnamed: 9': None}, {'model': 'homepage.territorymanager', 'pk': 2, 'Name': 'Aaron Martin ', 'Distributor': 'Pierce ###', 'State': 'PA', 'Brand': 'Bryant/Carrier', 'Cell': '267-###-####', 'email address': None, 'Notes': None, 'Unnamed: 9': None},...]
```

I am using this function to try and reformat

```
def re_serialize_reg_json(d, jsonFilePath):
    for i in d:
        d2 = {'Name': d[i]['Name'], 'Distributor' : d[i]['Distributor'], 'State' : d[i]['State'], 'Brand' : d[i]['Brand'], 'Cell' : d[i]['Cell'], 'EmailAddress' : d[i]['email address'], 'Notes' : d[i]['Notes']}
        d[i] = {'pk': d[i]['pk'],'model' : d[i]['model'], 'fields' : d2}
    print(d)
```

and it returns this error which doesn't make any sense because the format that django requires has a dictionary as the value of the third key:

```
d2 = {'Name': d[i]['Name'], 'Distributor' : d[i]['Distributor'], 'State' : d[i]['State'], 'Brand' : d[i]['Brand'], 'Cell' : d[i]['Cell'], 'EmailAddress' : d[i]['email address'], 'Notes' : d[i]['Notes']}
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Any help appreciated!

Here is what I did to get `d`:

```html
df = pandas.read_csv('/Users/justinbenfit/territorymanagerpython/territory managers - Sheet1.csv')
df.to_json('/Users/justinbenfit/territorymanagerpython/territorymanagers.json', orient='records')



jsonFilePath = '/Users/justinbenfit/territorymanagerpython/territorymanagers.json'

def load_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        d = json.load(f)
        return d
d = load_file(jsonFilePath)
print(d)
```

Comment: Is `d` a dictionary or a list? Looping over a dictionary gives you the keys of the dictionary, but looping over a list gives you the items in that list.

Answer (score 0):

D is actually a list containing multiple dictionaries, so in order to make it work you want to change that `for i in d` part to: `for i in range(len(d))`.

Comment: thanks! I have updated the original post with what I did to get d in the first place. Is there a way to create it as a dictionary to begin with so I can avoid working with a list? I'm assuming that working with a dictionary to begin with is superior but let me know if it doesn't matter. Thanks!